# How to access vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>> D[20]?

Tags: c++, vector

Is it correct to save information like this?

```
D[1].push_back(make_pair(x,make_pair(y,0));
```

I need 0 in the second position of that pair.

How do I access the values, for example:

```
int a,b;
```

I need a to get the value of `x`, `b` the value of `y`, and rise by 1, the last value (the 0 value from the second pair)

Is it correct like this?

```
a=D[1].first; 
b=D[1].second.first;
D[1].second.second++;
```

Comment: 1. Fix the formatting of your code 2. Don't tag C, this has nothing to do with C 3. What is the question? What problems do you have with your code?

Comment: You may want to consider a `std::vector` of `std::tuple<int, int, int>` instead. Better yet, store `struct`s.

Comment: I smell an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are declaring an array of 20 vectors. So right way would be

```
D[1].push_back(make_pair(0,make_pair(1,2));
int a = D[1][0].first;
pair<int,int> b = D[1][0].second;
b.second++; // You now have a pair containing increased value. Original remains unchanged.
int z = D[1][0].second.second; // contains the nested pair's second value
```

If you want to increase the second - then do it directly.

```
D[1][0].second.second++; // originally changed.
```

If you want to get pair which is in the last position you can get the size of the vector and validate and then get the last inserted element.